# Making new variable for drupal 7 theme showing error notice

Tags: variables, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

Hi I am trying to make a new variable for drupal 7 theme. My theme name is `ntheme`. For this I have defined a function in `template.php` :

```
function ntheme_gnu_preprocess(&$variables)
{
    $variables['disclaimer'] = t('Comments are unaythorized. The views expressed are those of the comment author.');
}
```

And used this variable `$disclaimer` in `comment-wrapper.tpl.php`:

```
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'): ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h2 class="title"><?php print t('Comments'); ?></h2>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

  <?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
    <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <p><?php print $disclaimer; ?></p>
</div>
```

But it showing Notice :

> Notice: Undefined variable: disclaimer in include() (line 39 of
>   C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\themes\ntheme\templates\comment-wrapper.tpl.php).

Whats wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your theme name ntheme_gnu or ntheme beacuse if ur theme name is ntheme u should call the hook_preprocess as ntheme_preprocess()